An integral identity involving a generalized hypergeometric function.
Let $\theta \ge 0$, $S\ge 0$, $\zeta \ge 0$ and $x \ge 0$ be real numbers and let $q \ge 1$ be an integer. Then the following identity below holds true:
\begin{equation}
G_\zeta(x) := \int\limits_0^\infty \underline{u^{-1+q \zeta} F_{1,q-1} \left[ \begin{array}{lll} 1+\zeta - S \theta \\ \left( \frac{j}{q} + \zeta \right)_{j=1}^{q-1} \end{array} ; - \frac{S^q u^q}{q^q S} \right]} \cdot e^{-S u x^{\frac{1}{q}}} du ={\mathfrak N}(q) \cdot \Gamma[\zeta] U\left[ \zeta, S \theta, S x \right] \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $U$ is the Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.
Here the normalization ${\mathfrak N}(q)$ depends on $q$ only and satisfies ${\mathfrak N}(1) = 1$.
The identity above is a generalization of the integral representation of the Kummer function see Wikipedia page on that.

We have discovered this identity in a following way.
Note that the right hand side of $(1)$ is a strictly decreasing eigenfunction of the following operator ${\mathfrak G}_x = (\theta-x) d/dx + 1/S d^2/dx^2$ to the eigenvalue $\zeta$.In other words ${\mathfrak G}_x G_\zeta(x) = \zeta G_\zeta(x) $ and the function in question is strictly decreasing.
But now by substituting $y = x^{1/q}$ we obtain the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
G_\zeta''(y)+G_\zeta'(y) \left(\theta  q S y^{q-1}-q S y^{2 q-1}+\frac{1-q}{y}\right)+\zeta
    \left(-q^2\right) S G_\zeta(y) y^{\left(2-\frac{2}{q}\right) q} = 0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, we seek a solution to $(2)$ in the form $G_\zeta(y) := \int\limits_0^\infty w_\zeta(u) e^{-A u y} $. Now multiplying $(2)$ by  $y$ and then inserting the ansatz into $(2)$ and integrating by parts and assuming that the surface terms vanish, gives a certain higher order ODE for the weight function $w_\zeta(u)$.
Then it turns out that the higher order ODE is satisfied by the term being underlined in $(1)$ when $A=S$. This finishes the derivation. All the steps are verified in the Mathematica code below:
Clear[\[Zeta], S, \[Theta], A, y, u, q, p, w, F, G, x, \[Epsilon]]; \
\[Epsilon] = -1;
ex = DSolveChangeVariables[
   Inactive[
     DSolve][(\[Theta] - x)  Derivative[1][F][x] + 
      x^(p/q)/S  Derivative[2][F][x] - \[Zeta]  F[x] == 0, F, x], G, 
   y, y == x^(1/q)];
ex = ex /. Inactive[DSolve][A_, _, _] :> A /. Equal[A_, 0] :> A;
ex = Collect[ex/Coefficient[ex, G''[y]], Derivative[n_][G][y], 
  PowerExpand[Simplify[#]] &]

ex = ex  y;
ex = ex /. G[y] :> Exp[\[Epsilon]  A  u  y] /. 
   Derivative[n_][G][
     y] :> (\[Epsilon]  A  u)^n  Exp[\[Epsilon]  A  u  y];
(*Use differential identity.*)
ex = Expand[ex] /. 
   y^q_.  Exp[\[Epsilon]  A  u  y] :> (\[Epsilon] )^q/(A)^q  mD[
      Exp[\[Epsilon]  A  u  y], {u, q}];
(*Integrate by parts.*)
ex1 = Expand[w[u] ex] /. 
   w_  mD[E^(\[Epsilon]  A  u  y), {u, q_}] :> (-1)^
      q  E^(\[Epsilon]  A  u  y)  D[w, {u, q}];
ex1 = Expand[ex1  E^(-\[Epsilon]  A  u  y)] // Simplify

ex2 = ex1 /. p :> q /. q :> 5;
ex2 = Activate[ex2, Unevaluated[Sum]];
DSolveValue[ex2 == 0, w, u]


In addition to this I provide another piece of code that verifies the identity $(1)$ directly.
{\[Theta], S, \[Zeta]} = RandomReal[{1, 3}, 3, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
Clear[w, u, q];
w[u_, q_?NumericQ] := 
  u^(-1 + q  \[Zeta])
      HypergeometricPFQ[{1 + \[Zeta] - S  \[Theta]}, 
    Table[j/q + \[Zeta], {j, 1, q - 1}], -((S^q  u^q)/(q^q  S))];
xs = Array[# &, 20, {1, 5}];
vals = Table[{#, 
      NIntegrate[w[u, q]  Exp[-S  u  #^(1/q)], {u, 0, Infinity}]} & /@
     xs, {q, 1, 3}];
vals1 = {#, 
     Gamma[\[Zeta]]  HypergeometricU[\[Zeta], S  \[Theta], S  #]} & /@
    xs;
ListPlot[
 Table[(#[[2]] & /@ vals[[q]])/(#[[2]] & /@ vals1), {q, 1, 3}]]



Having said all this my question would be how would one go about proving $(1)$ in some alternative, easier way?
